# RDD to pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, pyspark

I am trying to convert spark rdd in below format to pandas dataframe.

```
['f1\tf2\tf3\tf4\tf5','4.0\tNULL\t183.0\t190.0\tMARRIED']
```

When I execute the below code, line 3 gives the error: "Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':"

```
sparkDF = data.map(lambda x: str(x)) 
sparkDF2 = sparkDF.map(lambda w: w.split('\t'))
sparkDF3 = sparkDF2.toDF()
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

In pandas

```
x=['f1\tf2\tf3\tf4\tf5','4.0\tNULL\t183.0\t190.0\tMARRIED']
rdd=sc.parallelize(x)
#list=[l.split('\t') for l in ','.join(rdd.collect()).split(',')] 
#or
list=rdd.map(lambda x:x.split("\t")).collect()
import pandas as pnd
pnd.DataFrame(list)
```

[image]

In Spark

```
x=['f1\tf2\tf3\tf4\tf5','4.0\tNULL\t183.0\t190.0\tMARRIED']
rdd=sc.parallelize(x)
df=rdd.map(lambda x:x.split("\t")).toDF()
df.show()
+---+----+-----+-----+-------+
| _1|  _2|   _3|   _4|     _5|
+---+----+-----+-----+-------+
| f1|  f2|   f3|   f4|     f5|
|4.0|NULL|183.0|190.0|MARRIED|
+---+----+-----+-----+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks !! I tried this and I get "Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o22.applySchemaToPythonRDD.".